# Cassandra schema use set collection or multiple rows

Tags: collections, cassandra, schema, cql

I'm designing a keyspace in Cassandra that will hold information about groups of users.  Some info on it:

- Access to this data will only be made by requesting what users are contained in a certain group and updating the users that are contained in a group.
- Reads will be much more frequent than writes.
- Each group could contain up to 20,000 user IDs

I have two designs that I'm considering for this.

1. Multiple rows per group: The table would have two columns of type TEXT and be keyed on Primary Key (GroupID, UserID) and reading the users in a group would be done by `select * from table where GroupID = {GroupID}` and would return as many rows as there are users in the group.
2. One row per group using the Cassandra Set Collection: The table would have two columns, the first (GroupID) of type TEXT and the second (UserIDs) of type SET[TEXT] and be keyed on Pimary Key (GroupID).  Reading the users in a gorup would be done by `select * from table where GroupID = {GroupID}` and would return a single row with the set of user ids contained in its UserIDs column set.

I can't find a lot of documentation surrounding what would be the better design for this scenario.  Any thoughts or pros and cons to either scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a group of 20k user IDs, I would absolutely avoid using collections at all costs. Collections are a convenience feature, but they're not nearly as performant as using a traditional CQL data model where you have the `PRIMARY KEY(GroupID,UserID)` where all users are ordered in a single partition. That will be both easy to reason about, easy to query (can `SELECT` either a single partition and page through all group members, or you can `SELECT ... WHERE GroupID=X and UserID=Y` to determine if a user is in the group), and very performant.

Answer (score 3):

From Datastax:

[When to use collections](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddlWhenCollections.html)

[Using collections](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html)

Looks like in your case, using collections won't hit the allowable limits. Each item `UserID` is probably <=64K, and you have <= 20K entries, which is less than the 64K maximum.

However, as Jeff said, your performance will likely be much better using the compound key, partitioning by `GroupID` (your query column) and clustering by `UserID` (the values you are receiving from your query).